# Xcode 5 - "iOS Simulator failed to install application" every time I switch simulators

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios7, xcode5

Using Xcode 5 GM, anytime I switch to the 5.1, 6.0 or 6.1 simulators to test, I get the error "iOS Simulator failed to install application." When I reset the simulator it works, but this is getting very tiring.

Anybody have a permanent fix or workaround?

Comment: I got the same annoying error. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I was told it was related to the deployment target being 5.1, but changing that hasn't been conclusive.

Comment: I got different situation. My simulator for 6.0 is no problem. But I got the error message in iOS 7 simulator.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue. From the [Xcode 5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241):

> After switching the minimum deployment target of an application from
>   iOS 7.0 to a release prior to iOS 7.0, building and running the
>   application may fail with the message “iOS Simulator failed to install
>   the application.”
>
> - **Go to the iOS home screen, click and hold the application icon, then tap the hovering “X” button to delete the application.** 13917023

Another release note:

> iOS Simulator
>
> - If an iOS app is detached, relaunching the same app from Xcode will
>     result in a black screen in the Simulator even though the new app is
>     launched. Terminate the app in the Simulator or relaunch it for the
>     second time. 14648784

Comment: Using the hint from TRedman I changed the deployment target from 5.0 to 5.1 and the error is gone (for now). I ran the application ten consecutive times and no error message.

Comment: Unfortunately the simulator always in black screen even when there is no application running at all.

Comment: @bagusflyer Please see the edit to the answer. Sound like it's another known issue.

Comment: I'm running into this randomly: some projects exhibit this behaviour, others don't. So I can't mark this as correct unfortunately.

Comment: This is happening since developer preview 1, i think. Error message "iOS simulator failed to install an application" pops up even when application is not installed on simulator. There's no application to remove, and error does not go away for one of my projects. For other projects it's fine. Resetting simulator, removing derived data and cleaning does not help.

Comment: I am getting same issue for iPhine(4 inch retina) what should i do?

Comment: For me, this seems to be associated with switching between running in the simulator for iOS6 and iOS7; iOS7 works reliable and iOS6 works only after a reset or after deleting the app (deleting the app is *much* faster than reseting the simulator).  @TRedman, Thanks for asking and posting this answer.  Too bad Apple left us to clean up there mess.

Comment: It can also happen if Build field in your project settings is empty, does not have a number. Make sure to have at least 1.0 in it.

Comment: Another trick about the black screen if you know the app is running, you can go back to Home screen and tap the app icon and you will see the app as expected. Works most of the time.

Comment: Nothing described here worked for me. Finally I just restarted my machine and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

Delete the old version app in your simulator (usually iOS 6.x).

Comment: Thanks, that did it (I had previously deployed the app to the 5.1 and 6.0 Simulators using Xcode 4)

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, header over to iOS Simulator - Reset Content and Settings.

This can be easier when you have a lot of apps on the simulator and can't remember which one you're currently working on.

You need to do this for every iOS Simulator version that causes the problem.

Answer (score 10):

None of the other suggestions worked for me.  However, after comparing my existing app settings to a new vanilla project, I noticed that the "Build" field for my Target was blank.  Once I put something in that field, the app installed just fine!

Comment: Brilliant! That worked for me after I'd reset simulator content and removed all applications data manually many times!

Comment: Simply Brilliant...! you allowed to leave office now.

Comment: man! awesome. I had been sitting behind this issue for quite a long. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where can I find the 'Build' field for my Target?

Comment: Where is the "Build" field??

Answer (score 10):

if you have already developed project and you used xib to develop views then

X-Code > Inspector Selector Bar > Interface Builder Document > opens in > and change from Xcode Default(5.o)  to Xcode 4.6 . 

[image]

Build and Run your app it will run successfully, if it won't run again then, header over to iOS Simulator - Reset Content and Settings. delete old app from simulator then Run again.

Answer (score 9):

i got the same problem but solved by following way....

1. Launch the iOS Simulator
2. Go and click "iOS Simulator" menu
3. Click "Reset content and settings"
4. Close simulator and rebuild your app.

[image]

Above screen shot is showing the way how you can do this...

I think this works for you...!!!

Answer (score 7):

Deleting the app in the simulator works for me. 
just wanted to add that this happen only if I open xib that created in xcode 4.6
If it's other files, this not happen

Answer (score 3):

try this ....

in my case nothing have worked for me , after resetting the content simulator also , i am not able to install the app on simulator . after that i just changed my project location . i just moved the project to other location . then it installed successfully.

Comment: Does this mean location of folder enclosing project in Finder hierarchy? If so, `doesn't` work from me (my search continues...)

Comment: @cate yes , in my case i moved the folder from documents to desktop , it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

None of the above things worked for me. I just reinstalled xcode and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue today. Found it was an empty Reference Folder (blue folder) causing this. Removed the folder from Resources in Build Phase... cleaned build folder for the heck of it, and it went away.

Answer (score 1):

/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/ --> remove all contents of this folder, then simply launch the app from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

To check your Executable file settng ex.**$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)**
(Project setting - info property page)

Answer (score 0):

I have different issue when getting error message “iOS Simulator failed to install application”, the reason is because I have added a property in App-Info.plist without any value. For instance, [Application Category] with no value. Thus the error will show up as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, the image of the phone actually appeared, but the image of the app I wanted to test did not. Instead, I was on the main page of the phone that shows the apps you have.  I fixed this problem by deleting the many icons that appeared on the start screens - about 30 of them.  These had been created when I testing apps over the months.  So, not saying its a solution, but it started working after I deleted the old app images.

Comment: Basically you reset the simulator content: open simulator, choose "iOS Simulator" from (Mac OSX) menubar and "Reset Content and Settings..." submenu item.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `-framework XCTest`.

It made the app die with `iOS Simulator failed to install application`

and on the device `Could not inspect the application package.`

Removed it and now works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Xcode GM which is under beta stage. Use latest Xcode 5.1.1 available. 
Also, these error occur while switching between simulator (32 bit and 64 bit).

1. Quit the simulator and re-build the application. OR
2. Reset simulator from "iOS simulator" -> "Reset content and settings.."

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I changed my app name and bundle id midway.  I happened to delete the Executable File name in my plist.  I changed it back to "${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" (no quotes) and I'm back in business.