# xcode 5 issue : "iOS Simulator failed to install the application"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have just upgraded my xcode version to 5.0. After running application 2-3 times it's giving me error like this "**iOS Simulator failed to install the application**". This is working fine in old xcode. When I reset the simulator it works fine, but this is irritating again and again.

Can anybody tell me what is the real issue? How can i resolve it.

Did you find new solution for this thing?

[image]

Comment: Are you switching between SDK 6.1 and SDK 7.0?

Comment: no i m just using version iOS 6.0. Not even changing to SDK 7.0.

Comment: try this if this can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746093/xcode-5-ios-simulator-failed-to-install-application-every-time-i-switch-simu

Comment: check my answer. may be it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `CMD+SHFT+K` and quit the simutor and then run again and it's working, no need to reset simulator or delete an applicaiton.I'm not sure but some time it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try manually launch the iOS Simulator and from the "iOS Simulator" menu, click "Reset content and settings", then close and rebuild your app. It worked for me.

Comment: i wrote same thing there. but how many times i shall do that?

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem but solved by following way....

1. launch the iOS Simulator
2. Go and click "iOS Simulator" Menu
3. click "Reset content and settings"
4. close simulator and rebuild your app.

[image]

Above screen shot is showing the way how you can do this...

I think this works for you...!!!

Comment: just see my answer no need to reset.

Comment: I got it Nirav but what r u saying is same as my opinion...You r doing the task by shortcuts and i m using menu...[See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the application from the simulator and build it again.
Or try to use a device with different iOS version.

Comment: Then you should cross your fingers and wait for an Xcode upgrade.
(BTW i had similar issues before Xcode5 too its not a new problem)