# Xcode 5 IOS simulator black screen and app install fails

Tags: xcode, ios7, osx-mountain-lion, xcode5

I just updated my xcode to work with ios7. Now whenever I make a new app, even if its set to build for ios7, I get an error in the simulator when running. It says that the install failed, even if I just made the project and haven't coded anything into it yet. The simulator also shows a black screen. I have tried the reset content, and it didn't work. I saw something somewhere saying to delete the Iphone Simulator folder in application support, but no such folder seems to exist. What can I try to do?

**Update--**

With some additional research, I found that Iphone Simultor is in the Xcode.app now, but I don't know what to delete. There are many files under the iPhone Simulator Folder. If I delete the actual app, it just doesnt open. Any ideas?? I dont even get an iphone on the screen, just a black window...

Update 2:

Even when I just go to open developer tools -> iphone simulator 
it still gives me just a black screen....[image]

[image]

Update 3

I just re-installed X-code, and all works now! Strange....I have no idea what happened...But I thought I would let y'all know for others who have similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the iOS Simulator folder of the iOS version in question in

```
/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```

helps, but then you always have to repeat all the settings you made in the simulator (language, for example). Try to press the home button and then delete your app like you do it on a real iOS device. You should then be able to install it again.

This seems to be a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746093/xcode-5-ios-simulator-failed-to-install-application-every-time-i-switch-simu?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the folder, and still no luck...It still says install failed...But also, to clarify, I don't even get an iphone on the screen when it loads, just a black window

Comment: What happens when you select “Open Developer Tool”->”iOS Simulator” in Xcode? Do you still get the black window?

Comment: This worked for me. I quit the sim and ran this command: `sudo rm -rd ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/`, after which I was able to launch the sim from the Finder and see the springboard.

Answer (score 2):

When simulator open - Go to iOS simulator tab -> reset content and settings..
Work for me.

Comment: To be clear, Elad is referring to the iOS Simulator menu item in the simulator app. But that selection did nothing for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919959/iphone-simulator-folder-not-in-application-support) answer will help?

The simulator should be in this folder:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iOS Simulator.app
```

Comment: This seems to be old. It now is in the Xcode.app itself, but thank you anyway! I wouldn't have found that out without this comment...

Comment: I did some digging myself and found it in this folder: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]

Comment: Also, could you post a screenshot of the error you're getting?

Comment: I tried deleting that folder too, still just a black screen...And I get the error message

Comment: So did you try deleting the application icon? By holding down the mouse button on the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any @try and @catch(NSException *exception) {} blocks are not commented or are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version mismatch between your OS X version and your Xcode (iOS simulator)
and it seems that you have upgraded your OS X so Xcode needs to be upgraded as well, Check the versions that match with each other.

## You need to upgrade your Xcode which will upgrade iOS simulator.

Good Luck,