# iOS Simulator launching Black screen Appear

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

[image]

xcode 4.6 and Ios simulator version 6.1

run the projects given error occurred 
   following Scenarios not worked

1.change the debugger from LLDB to GDB.

given message appear in xcode:

GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824) (Thu Nov 15 10:42:43 UTC 2012)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".

2.Delete derived Data given path

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications and ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

my system only available in following folder path:

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/

3.try to iOS Simulator option reset to reset content and settings

Comment: Did you quit Xcode while doing that?

Comment: have u recently changed ur app display name or something?

Comment: yes changed my display name

Comment: hi manujmv reset username and password for my system after display name system administrator previous one name is diffrent

Comment: Are you trying to run in release mode?  Check your schemes.  You can't debug an app that has been signed with a distribution certificate (the default on release builds).

Comment: There is a similar question,which may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041556/xcode-5-ios-simulator-black-screen-and-app-install-fails/22476361#22476361

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me it was, that I forgot to set my storyboard as the main interface in the project editor.

Comment: There are many scenarios, all of them soul crushing for a developer... In my case, somehow, dont ask me how... the main view was set as opaque!! Click on view-> Attributtes Inspector > Opaque

Answer (score 4):

Try this ..

1. Reset your simulator.
2. Product -> Clean.

[image]

This has worked for me.

Comment: then i think there is an error on appdelegate do you set the rootView? check the spelling

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  Resetting simulator did nothing and closing xcode also did nothing.  Solved by simply rebooting my computer.

Comment: Also, as a side note - with xcode5 and ios7 my simulator has slowed down considerably on my aging mac - a good dose of patience on older systems helps too.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your simulator's content.[image]

Then reset your xcode.

Make sure, reset current using simulator.

Comment: @rajesh57 which ios simulator(version) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First You go to the Product->Scheme->Manage Scheme.
Now you need to delete all the schemes you created. Now just click on **Autocreate Scheme Now**. Just clean your project and reset the simulator and Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was a deep build clean. Cmd-Alt-shift-K